# Angular in production

Tags: angularjs, apache, laravel, digital-ocean

I've made an angular app. Not fully completed, but it's working fine on my localhost.
I bought a DigitalOcean droplet and I've pushed my app in there.

The problem is that when I click on a link, everything is loaded properly. But then the link just goes to the root link. Is there something you have to set in some kind of configuration for angular apps from development to production mode?

Maybe it has something to do with my apache2 config? Again, everything is working fine on localhost.

**FYI: I'm using the `Laravel` framework as REST api.**

My server is accessible at: `http://95.85.10.155/`

Hope someone has a solution.

Comment: Be more specific: What link of your App, what apache config (local vs. remote)...

Answer (score 0):

Do you have mod_rewrite installed/enabled? Laravel requires it. See the installation documentation for more information.

http://laravel.com/docs/installation

Answer (score 0):

Well, it's solved. The .htaccess didn't rewrite the .index.php in the url. So I've tweaked it and it all good now.